# Two arrays in foreach loop.

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I want to fill in the table. The database is filling the array, but this method didn't work. What is the problem? How to use foreach loop?

```
<?php
    $a = $db->prepare("select * 
                       from sabit_sayfalar 
                       inner join alt_sayfa on sabit_sayfalar.sayfa_id = alt_sayfa.ustsayfaid");
    $a->execute(array());
    $b = $a->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $c = $a->rowCount();

    $q = $db->prepare("select * 
                       from sabit_sayfalar 
                       inner join alt_sayfa on sabit_sayfalar.sayfa_id = alt_sayfa.altsayfaid");
    $q->execute(array());
    $w = $q->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $e = $q->rowCount();

     if($c){
         foreach($b as $w and $m as $n){                    
?>      

<tbody> 
    <tr> 
        <td>                    
            <?php echo $m["sayfa_adi"];?>   
        </td>   
        <td>
            <?php echo ($n["sayfa_adi"]);?>
        </td>   
    </tr>
<?php                   
        }
    }       
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: To be honest, it looks pretty messy. Let me write you an example.

Comment: I've just started,i do not know enough.soryy :( thank you I'm waiting

Comment: What does "didnt work" mean? Why do you think you can use `and` in between a foreach loop?

Comment: What does the arrays look like? Are they indexed or associative?

Comment: Foreach only accepts one array as input, it won't work because of that anyway.

Comment: Dilara, it's ok to not know enough. Everybody is learning. But look, here's a good place for you to test your code (with fake data inside arrays and so on) before pushing for a server. http://phptester.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came out with.

```
<?php
    $firstQuery = $db->prepare("select * 
                       from sabit_sayfalar 
                       inner join alt_sayfa on sabit_sayfalar.sayfa_id = alt_sayfa.ustsayfaid");
    $firstQuery->execute(array());
    $firstQueryResults = $firstQuery->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $firstQueryCount = $firstQuery->rowCount();

    $secondQuery = $db->prepare("select * 
                       from sabit_sayfalar 
                       inner join alt_sayfa on sabit_sayfalar.sayfa_id = alt_sayfa.altsayfaid");
    $secondQuery->execute(array());
    $secondQueryResults = $secondQuery->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $secondQueryCount = $secondQuery->rowCount();

    if ($firstQueryCount > 0 && $secondQueryCount > 0) {
?>      

<tbody> 
<?php foreach ($firstQueryResults as $firstQueryKey => $firstQueryRow) { ?>
    <tr> 
        <td>                    
            <?php echo $firstQueryRow["sayfa_adi"];?>   
        </td>   
        <td>
            <?php echo ($secondQueryResults[$firstQueryKey]["sayfa_adi"]);?>
        </td>   
    </tr>
<?php                   
        }
    }       
?>
</tbody>
```

I changed the names of the variables for readability, and I adapted the table for using the information you provided... there are still some flaws connected with indexes that might be different for each SELECT, but that is another problem.

I also interpreted some variables that were missing as the variables you had but, for some reason, wrote wrong.

Comment: `$secondQueryCount`? not `$secondQueryResults`? (at the second echo) This looks more like I would think it should be. But if the arrays is indexed differently then it will not work.

Comment: Kurwa! Thank you. Yeah. But I agree, chances are of 99 errors for every 2 lines xD

Comment: Probably move the opening body above the loop too.

Comment: Funny how I cared more for the PSR stuff than for the HTML section.

Answer (score -2):

you cannot be used and in a foreach i think you want to use 2 foreach here and your `<tbody>` should be out of the loop